# Failed to restart motd-news.service

Tags: server, virtualbox, vagrant, motd

I am receiving a message saying Failed to restart motd-news.service when starting up ubuntu 16.04.6 on a vagrant box (Homestead).

Trying to get the message go away, but not sure how to do so. Cannot find any packages related to motd (message of the day) either.

Hope for some guidance

Comment: I'd also like to figure this out as I am getting the same issue on a fresh vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

The reason it fails is usually because of measures taken to harden the system. It will fail because it lacks permissions.

```
root@foobar-sys01:/home/mike# systemctl status motd-news.service
● motd-news.service - Message of the Day
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/motd-news.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-03-29 04:05:29 UTC; 26min ago
TriggeredBy: ● motd-news.timer
       Docs: man:update-motd(8)
   Main PID: 2387022 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[2387022]: motd-news.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[2387022]: motd-news.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news: Permission denied
Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 29 04:05:29 foobar-sys01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Message of the Day.
```

If you were to just disable the motd service the systemd timer will still try to do it's thing and the unit will fail.

If you want to be fancy you can do this. The `--now` flag tells `systemctl` to stop any currently running instances of the service.

```
systemctl disable --now motd-news.service motd-news.timer && systemctl daemon-reload
```

Or just do this:

```
systemctl disable motd-news.service
systemctl disable motd-news.timer
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then run these:

```
systemctl reset-failed
systemctl status
```